# How can I find the image style source from a template file?

Tags: views, 8, theming

Why cannot I use `{{ file_url(node.field_image.0.entity.uri.value) }}` in a view?

> [image: screenshot]

It does not return */drupal-8.6.1/sites/default/files/2018-10/gen9C52.tmp.jpeg* as I expect.

Comment: You could set your view display to use a custom view mode (as opposed to fields) and then you would have full access to the node object. Then you can use "node view" templates for your view using your standard  Twig node theming that you're probably used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why I can't use {{ file_url(node.field_image.0.entity.uri.value) }} in
>   my custom view

Simply because your view does not have access to the node variable object.

You can use [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module. Then add your image field and for formatter select Image URL.